# How to synchronize multiple Video Clips based on background music

Tags: davinci-resolve, sync, premiere-pro

I’m working on a dance video project where there are multiple clips of people dancing to the same song. I want to synchronize these clips so that they match the beats of the music. How can I achieve this using DaVinci Resolve or Adobe Premiere Pro? (I have access to both).

The background music is the same song for all clips and it is recorded from a camera, so there is some level of additional noise.
I need a method to align these clips, so that I can cut to another clip without missing the beats of the music.
Is there a feature in DaVinci Resolve or Premiere Pro that can automatically synchronize the clips based on the audio waveform?